# How to report XHR data when use jQuery.ajax() ifModified:true? On repeated ajax request it reports data undefined

Tags: ajax, json, jquery, undefined

How to report XHR `data` when use jQuery.ajax() `ifModified:true`? Unfortunately on repeated ajax request it reports `data undefined`.

```
$.ajax({
    type:"GET",
    url:'/api',                    // {"content"="Hello!"}
    dataType:'json',
    cache:true,
    ifModified:true,
    success:function(data,textStatus,jqXHR){
        console.debug(textStatus); //repeated request returns `notmodified`
        console.debug(data);       // Why on repeated request returns `undefined`?
    }
});
```

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5118017/how-to-fix-browser-cache-and-notmodified-respond-for-json-jquery-ajaxifmodifi/12653101#12653101

Answer (score 0):

If you've set modified mode and remote page no-modified, the status code 304 will be return; i suggest you try to place your function code in ajax "complete" event.

http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.1.js

```
// If not modified
if ( status === 304 ) {

    statusText = "notmodified";
    isSuccess = true;

// If we have data
} else {

    try {
        success = ajaxConvert( s, response );
        statusText = "success";
        isSuccess = true;
    } catch(e) {
        // We have a parsererror
        statusText = "parsererror";
        error = e;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why it returns me `parsererror`? I tried to set up it for https://github.com/laukstein/ajax-seo/blob/master/index.php Any advices?